# Momentjs firstday of week

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayofweek

I am using momentjs. I would like to change the first day of week to Monday and somehow it works.

```
moment.locale('en', {
        week : {
            dow : 1 // Monday is the first day of the week
        }
    });
```

If I type `moment().startOf('week').format('dddd DD-MM-YYYY')`, it Shows
"Monday 19-01-2015"

But if I type `moment().year(2014).week(4).day(0)`, it will shows as 
"Sunday 18-01-2015"

Anyone knows why it got this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The `day` function is not locale aware.  it always uses Sunday as day 0.

Use the `weekday` function instead - which *is* locale aware.

See the docs for [`day`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) and [`weekday`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/), which explain this pretty well.